# /dev/tcp/hostname/80: as an interactive session?

Tags: networking, shell, shell-script

Does anyone know how to obtain an interactive session with the device `/dev/tcp/hostname/80`?

I opened using `cat <> /dev/tcp/www.google.com/80` and tried typing in 'GET / HTTP/1.0\nHost: www.google.com\n', however there was no response.

The following works, but the session is non-interactive:

```
{ echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r" >&3; cat <&3 ; } 3<> /dev/tcp/www.google.com/80
```

Comment: I don't know if this is it, but `\n` (newline) on Unix is defined as a bare linefeed character, whereas HTTP for arcane reasons requires DOS-like carriage return / linefeed pairs (CRLFs; \r\n). Also, it requires **two** CRLF pairs at the end of the request headers (\r\n\r\n).

Comment: I tried CTL-V CTRL-M <ret> (where in unix ctrl-v means the next character is treated literally).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sole `<>` is equivalent to `0<>`. When you do `cat <> /dev/tcp/…`, the stdin of `cat` is redirected. `cat` does not read from the terminal. What you type goes to nowhere.

The command that allegedly works

> ```
> { echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r" >&3; cat <&3 ; } 3<> /dev/tcp/www.google.com/80
> ```

sends the output of `echo` to the connection, and the response to `cat`. Again, nothing reads what you (are going to) type.

The important thing is `cat` is uni-directional. To communicate interactively you need one `cat` per direction:

```
{ cat <&3 &
  cat >&3
} 3<> /dev/tcp/www.google.com/80
```

The first `cat` (in the background) reads from the connection and writes to the terminal (screen). The second `cat` reads from the terminal (what you type) and prints to the connection.

When the connection is terminated, `cat` in the background exits automatically; there is no need to kill it explicitly.

Bi-directional tools like `nc` can do this when invoked just once:

```
nc www.google.com 80
```

By default what `nc` reads from stdin goes to the connection, and the response goes to stdout.